# Fill blank cells in Pandas dataframe with value from cell above it

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Consider a situation.

```
A    B    C
1    X    Park
2    Y    
3    Z    Team
4    L
5    M    Cycle
6    K    
7    N
```

Expected output:

```
A    B    C
1    X    Park
2    Y    Park
3    Z    Team
4    L    Team
5    M    Cycle
6    K    Cycle
7    N    Cycle
```

There are millions of rows so can not be done manually.
Gaps between empty cells and cells with values can be more than 1000s of rows in column C.

Comment: Can you guarantee the order of A? If so I can help.

Comment: Can we do it on index based method?

Comment: If not then yes I can maintain this order of A column.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need Pandas ffill():

```
df.ffill()
```

See the pandas documentation for parameters: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html

Answer (score 2):

Once you have NaN values for empty locations (this way you are specifically targetting the empty locations)

```
df[df[0]==""] = np.NaN
```

you can do this (In case you already have `NaN` in those location you can directly use this method. I mentioned this way since whenever we read from a CSV file or something, those empty portions comes blank)

```
df.fillna(method='ffill')
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
# importing pandas as pd
import pandas as pd
 
# Creating the dataframe
df=pd.DataFrame({"A":[5,3,None,4],
                 "B":[None,2,4,3],
                 "C":[4,3,8,5],
                 "D":[5,4,2,None]})
 
# Print the dataframe
df
```

[image]

Then.

```
df = df.ffill(axis = 0)
df
```

[image]